# Record decimal without space over 999

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in Mysql i setup row

```
 name        |   type
total_price  |  decimal(15,4)
```

If data is 999 record is 999.0000 that fine but if data is 1 000 (with space) record is 1
how can i fix this ?

I look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php but didnt find anything

Comment: `1 000` is not a valid number literal in (most) programming languages. Why do you have numbers with spaces?

Comment: Don't confuse data storage with data display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$var='1 000';
float(str_ireplace(' ','', $var));
```